# Chrome REST client always requesting GET instead of POST

Tags: ajax, node.js, rest

Looks like all the REST Client tools on my Chrome suddenly do not send POST requests properly. They send GET requests even though I select the POST option.

I am developing a web application using node.js backend server. I always use the chrome extension "Postman - REST Client" for testing my backend services. For example, I have a /foo handler which receives POST requests and returns some results, and a /bar handler that receives GET requests.
I could test those handlers properly until yesterday, when my POST requests to /foo get a response: "Cannot GET /foo", which normally happens when I send a GET request to /foo. And when I send POST requests to /bar (which normally should return "Cannot POST /bar") but get no error message but a proper GET result.

I tried some other REST Client tools on Chrome, like "REST Console", "Advanced REST Client", but all of them have the same behavior. However, my frontend webpage can access those handlers correctly with AJAX POST/GET calls. Is anything wrong with my backend server, or my Chrome browser?

Comment: All REST Client tools cannot be wrong at the same time right? May be you should look into your application.

Comment: Always helpful to use the Chrome Network inspector to see what request is eventually sent.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. The reason was that the site I was testing only allowed https. All plain http requests were redirected to a https URL (this was done at the webserver level). This redirect caused the rest-client to do an additional request (this time a GET request). 
This was the request that actually got through to my application server but then produced the error "Method GET not supported".

All I had to do was change the URL I used from http to https.